# Django using Aws S3 bucket to get static files

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, heroku

```
url.com/:9 GET https://<AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME>.s3.amazonaws.com/static/user/main.css net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
```

url.com is the actual site and AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME is the bucket name

When I try to retrieve my S3 file  from my base.html I get a 403 forbidden error in the console.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'user/main.css' %}" type="text/css">
```

Settings.py

```
# All of this is in my console.aws.amazon to configure aws s3 static files only
# IAM Management Console
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID') 
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY') 
# Amazon S3 Buckets
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME =  os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME') 
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}
AWS_LOCATION = 'static'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'pages/static'),
]
STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)
# For some reason I needed static root to collectstatistics
# STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
      
]
```

Comment: Hi, your S3 bucket are public?

Comment: Not public currently. I have the block public access.

Comment: What I do what is a statics files for base.html and a seperate one for a logged in account.

Comment: In the past i had a problem with private buckets and i resolved as here https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-instance-access-s3-bucket/

Comment: Have you tried to add `AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = "s3v4"`?

Comment: Did nothing and I switched Bucket to public block off and still nothing.

Comment: Is there anything I need to add in Bucket policy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3::<bucket_name>/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Adding that in Bucket policy in my AWS S3 permissions seemed to work.