# How can I serve staticfiles in Django in Railway app when Debug is False

Tags: django, image, url

When I set DEBUG to False on Railway's variables my images from uploads are not loading.

How can I fix that?

my settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
     ...
]


STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static'
]

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "uploads"
MEDIA_URL = "/uploads/"
```

my urls.py has

```
  + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) \
  + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

and I used

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using aws S3 bucket to render and store the images

Check out this link `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70356716/django-using-aws-s3-bucket-to-get-static-files`

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing between Media vs static files.

Media = user uploaded files.

Static files = css or js.

If you want to serve user uploaded files, unfortunately it cannot be served in DEBUG=False or production. You need to host it somewhere. Railway just launch volume. You can host is there.
If static files, then its okay.
You can put it alongside with your code.

Refer here: https://testdriven.io/blog/django-static-files/